# Puppeteer Google Cloud Function Pub/Sub Trigger can't open browser

Tags: google-cloud-functions, puppeteer, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create a Puppeteer function in GCP which can be triggered by Pub/Sub messages. The function is callable, but doesn't behave as expected and throws a Timeout Error once browser tries to initialize. Could the trigger possibly be using a NodeJS environment different from HTTP trigger?

I'm also very new to NodeJS, so I apologize ahead of time if the issue is blatantly obvious.

I've created an HTTP trigger for the function which behaves as expected. I copy/paste the Puppeteer Function below into the index.js when creating the Cloud Function, but separated in example for clarity that both triggers are running the identical function.

Puppeteer Function

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

scrapeUglyWebsite = () => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            args: ['--no-sandbox']
        })
            .then(async (browser) => {
                const page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.goto('http://suzannecollinsbooks.com/', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0})
                    .then(async () => {
                        //Wait for content to load
                        await page.waitForFunction('document.body !== null && document.body.innerText.includes(\'Jon Scieszka\')');
                        //Evaluate page contents
                        const dom_eval = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerText.includes("Here’s a picture of me with a rat"));
                        await browser.close();
                        resolve(dom_eval);
                    });
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
};
```

HTTP Trigger - index.js

```js
exports.cloudFunctionTest = (req, res) => {
    scrapeUglyWebsite()
        .then((results) => {
            if(results) {
                res.send('Suzanne Collins takes pictures with rats.');
            } else {
                res.send("Suzzane Collins doesn't take pictures with rats.");
            };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.send(err.toString());
        });
```

Pub/Sub Trgger - index.js

```js
exports.cloudFunctionTest = (data, context) => {
    scrapeUglyWebsite()
        .then((results) => {
            if(results) {
                console.log('Suzanne Collins takes pictures with rats.');
            } else {
                console.log("Suzzane Collins doesn't take pictures with rats.");
            };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.toString());
        });
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

HTTP Trigger behaves correctly with the expected result

```
Suzanne Collins takes pictures with rats.
```

Pub/Sub Trigger throws the following error with no output

```
TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to Chrome! The only Chrome revision guaranteed to work is r662092
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late but the reason that the TimeoutError occurs is because cloud functions do not automatically wait for async tasks to finish completing. So in `exports.cloudFunctionTest`, `scrapeUglyWebsite()` is called but the function does not wait for the promise to be fulfilled, so the program terminates. Hence the error

More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#terminating_background_functions) on how background functions work in NodeJs

In order for the function to wait for `scrapeUglyWebsite()`, you need to return a promise that completes when `scrapeUglyWebsite()` and the resulting code is complete.

Personally, I got it to work by simply wrapping the code currently in the function I am exporting in another async function and then returning the promise of the wrapper function.

```
async function wrapper() {
    try {
        const result = await scrapeUglyWebsite(); 
        if(results) {
            console.log('Suzanne Collins takes pictures with rats.');
        } else {
            console.log("Suzzane Collins doesn't take pictures with rats.");
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
    }
}
```

Then in the function you want to export:

```
exports.cloudFunctionTest = (data, context) => {
    return wrapper();
};
```